# ¿Puedo crear algo parecido a un JFileChooser en MatLab con App Designer?

Tags: matlab

intento leer archivos, especificamente una imagen, desde la GUI de MatLab con App Designer. ¿Es esto posible? ¿Cómo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con la función `uigetfile`, con la cual seleccionas archivos de forma interactiva, con la posibilidad, claro, de adicionar filtros sobre los tipos de archivos que te interesan.

En el siguiente enlace puedes encontrar varios ejemplos: [uigetfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html).

Comment: Gracias, el mismo día que publique la respuesta encontré la solución. Supongo que tendré que darte la solución. StackOverflow ES anda algo escaso de comunidad.